# Why isn't VB code to execute stored procedure changing the table?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Using Visual Studio 2010 I have created a VB Web Application which I added a database to.  I have a VB class which is suppose to take a name and add it to the database through a stored procedure. I run the code and it passes the variable to the vb class but doesn't seem to change the table once I've stopped running the program.

I'm new to the vb and visual studios thing so I'm using http://www.macronimous.com/resources/calling_stored_procedures_from_ASP.NET_and_VB.NET.asp as my guide which is why the code is the way it is.

Here is the vb class

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class human

Private name As String
Private id As Integer

Public Function sendName(ByVal nm As String)

    Dim SQLCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=
 C:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\
 WebApplication3\WebApplication3\App_Data\Database1.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

    SQLCon.Open()
 'I want to to execute the procedure addName using the variable nm
    SQLCmd.CommandText = "addName"
    SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nm)
    SQLCmd.Connection = SQLCon 'Active Connection
    SQLCon.Close()

    Return (nm)
End Function

End Class

and here's my stored procedure "addName"
Alter PROCEDURE addName (@GivenName varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Insert into tableA (name) values (@GivenName);
END
return
```

What am I missing that prevents the table from showing updates after I stop debugging the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great. You define a command, you create a connection and open it. But you fail to *execute* the command.

```
SQLCmd.Connection = SQLCon 'Active Connection
SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLCon.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You omitted a statement `SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  'You need this line
SQLCon.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the ExecuteNonQuery() method.

```
SQLCon.Open()
SQLCmd.CommandText = "addName"
SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nm)
SQLCmd.Connection = SQLCon 'Active Connection
SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  'This one is missing
SQLCon.Close()
```